# MOdalPopupExtender Hiding Problem with Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a modalpopupExtender which is opened when edit button is clicked.In that i have a gridview in which if click any row the popup gets hidden and the values are displayed on the page.The problem is that when i keep this code in the update panel the modalpopupextender is not getting hidden after clicking in the gridview.I have a master page in my page and using Ajax modal popup extender

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same behavior what i did was putting modelpopup before update panel that way it worked

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeScreenFreez"
                        runat="server" 
                        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                        DropShadow="true" 
                        TargetControlID="btnDummy"
                        PopupControlID="panFreeze">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="panFreeze" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display:none;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSave" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Sending the Quote....">
    </asp:Label>                                        
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnDummy" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDirectHomOwnrPremQuote" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you doing a full postback? If so, in the Click event why not use ModalPopup.Hide()??